# Julia memory allocation in simple size statement

Tags: profiling, julia, allocation

I am running the following routine in with `--track-allocation=user`. The routine is called in a for loop. Still I am surprised at the allocation generated in the first line: I would expect `numqps` to be allocated on the stack and thus not contributing to the final allocation count.

```
        - function buildpoints{T}(cell::Cell{T}, uv)
        - 
  2488320     numqps::Int = size(uv,2)
 12607488     mps = Array(Point{T}, numqps)
        0     for i in 1 : numqps
        0         mps[i] = buildpoint(cell, Vector2(uv[1,i], uv[2,i]))
        -     end
        - 
        0     return mps
        - 
        - end
```

**EDIT**: A bit further along in the memory profiling output I find:

```
  1262976 numcells(m::Mesh) = size(m.faces,2)
```

It seems the `size` function on Arrays is implemented not very efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was calling `size` on a variable declared as

```
type MyType{T}
    A::Array{T}
end
```

So the type of `A` was only partially declared, i.e. only the eltype was supplied, not the number of dimensions. I noticed similar allocation overheads when accessing elements (`A[i,j]`). Allocation disappeared when I declared instead

```
type MyType{T}
    A::Array{T,2}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> In interpreting the results, there are a few important details. Under
>   the user setting, the first line of any function directly called from
>   the REPL will exhibit allocation due to events that happen in the REPL
>   code itself. More significantly, JIT-compilation also adds to
>   allocation counts, because much of Julia’s compiler is written in
>   Julia (and compilation usually requires memory allocation). **The
>   recommended procedure is to force compilation by executing all the
>   commands you want to analyze, then call Profile.clear_malloc_data()
>   (page 594) to reset all allocation counters. Finally, execute the
>   desired commands** and quit Julia to trigger the generation of the .mem
>   files.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am taking into account these caveats already: I run the code before profiling to warm up the JIT, then call clear_malloc_data. Moreover, the code is called indirectly, this is not a top level function.